# Finding Big O Notation Clarification without function

Tags: time, complexity-theory

So this example was on this site and it was pretty clear, but what if you have this instead:
N, average sec:(1,000: 2.7)(2,000: 3.04) (4,000: 3.6)(8,000: 3.7)(16,000: 4)?
N doubles every time (2*N) and the average time starts to level off. I can guess from looking at the examples below (O(logN)), but can someone clarify how you would calculate the problem?

O(1): known as Constant complexity

1 item: 1 second
10 items: 1 second
100 items: 1 second

The number of items is still increasing by a factor of 10, but the scaling factor of O(1) is always 1.

O(log n): known as Logarithmic complexity

1 item: 1 second
10 items: 2 seconds
100 items: 3 seconds
1000 items: 4 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You'd do a regression analysis based on a log curve fit. You can start by plotting your data to get a visual confirmation.

A `log fit` in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%20fit%20%7B1000%2C%202.7%7D%2C%7B2000%2C%203.04%7D%2C%20%7B4000%2C%203.6%7D%2C%7B8000%2C%203.7%7D%2C%7B16000%2C%204%7D) would for example produce:

[image: log fit]

This shows that you're right and the growth seems to be logarithmic (for the provided data).

However, be aware that time measurements are not equal to an actual complexity analysis which is a formal proof rather than a curve fit to empirical data (which can be distorted for a number of reasons).